# How to use the while loop as a way to "pause" a process? (Using loop as an alternative to Threading)

Tags: java, multithreading, loops

I want to allow the process new LongDistanceCalls() to finish creating an instance first before continuing on the rest of program. However I am stuck and my solution so far is the following:

```
int count = 1;
do
{
    new LongDistanceCalls();
    count++;
}while(count ==1);
new LongDistanceCallsTWO();
```

Is it possible to use loop to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Use a reference and test if it is not null. Or use a static variable within the `LongDistanceCalls` that incrmeents when an object is created and test it. There are plenty of ways actually.

Comment: Why do you need to loop/pause here? When putting the calls directly uderneath eachother, the Thread has to wait on the first initialization before it can continue to the other. The loop trick is meant to pause an thread waiting till another thread is finnished, though right here there is just one thread. What did you expect to happen? Why would/wouldn't the usual way not work?